# Sum array of object of a key is returning NaN for more than 2 items in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, reduce

Following is my array -

```
const products = [{
  id: "1",
  quantity: 3
}, {
  id: "2",
  quantity: 3
}]

console.log(products.reduce((acc, product) => acc.quantity + product.quantity)) // 6 -> Correct
```

But if array contains more than 2 items it is throwing `NaN` as a result, Let me know what I am doing wrong here.

```
const products = [{
  id: "1",
  quantity: 3
}, {
  id: "2",
  quantity: 3
}, {
  id: "3",
  quantity: 4
}]
console.log(products.reduce((acc, product) => acc.quantity + product.quantity)) // NaN -> InCorrect
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cause `acc` is 6 the second time, `acc.quantity` is undefined. To solve this, replace `acc.quantity` with `acc` and use `0` as a starting accumulator

Answer (score 6):

The accumulator's initial value, by default, is the first element in the array. If the first element is an *object*, then adding anything to the object will result in `NaN`.

Simply provide another argument to `reduce` to provide the initial value for the accumulator, and ensure the accumulator logs the *sum*:

```js
const products = [{
  id: "1",
  quantity: 3
}, {
  id: "2",
  quantity: 3
}, {
  id: "3",
  quantity: 4
}];

const total = products.reduce((acc, product) => acc + product.quantity, 0);
console.log(total);
```

If you *really wanted* to have the accumulator store an object instead, you could do that, but it would mutate the first element in the array, you would have to make sure to access the appropriate property in order to log it:

```js
const products = [{
  id: "1",
  quantity: 3
}, {
  id: "2",
  quantity: 3
}, {
  id: "3",
  quantity: 4
}]
console.log(products.reduce((acc, product) => {
  acc.quantity += product.quantity;
  return acc;
}).quantity)
```

But that's a *really* bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

The [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) method applies a function against an accumulator and each element in the array (from left to right) to reduce it to a single value.

In your `acc` variable it contain value not object you directly add with new quantity like this

**DEMO**

```js
const products = [{
  id: "1",
  quantity: 3
}, {
  id: "2",
  quantity: 3
}, {
  id: "3",
  quantity: 4
}];

let result = products.reduce((acc, {quantity}) => acc +quantity, 0);

console.log(result)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {  max-height: 100% !important;  top: 0;}
```

Answer (score 1):

> This works perfectly fine

```
<script>
       const products = [{id: "1", quantity: 3},{id: "2", 
       quantity: 3},{id: "3", quantity: 4}];  

       total = Object.values(products).reduce((t, n) => t       
      + n.quantity, 0);

    console.log(total);
    </script>
```